# how to use static build of cpprest-sdk generated by vcpkg?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, casablanca, cpprest-sdk, vcpkg

I want to use `cpprestsdk` as static library for my project, I used the `vcpkg` tool to get the static library by entering the command: `vcpkg install cpprestsdk:x86-windows-static`, I have the following `lib` files under my installed directory in vcpkg folder, I was wondering If I want to link my application to `cpprestsdk` I only need to link it with the resulting `cpprest_2_10.lib`? or I should add all the other libs?

[image]

Comment: You need to add all the libs manually in proper dependency order. Use "vcpkg integrate install" to automatically insert the packages to your project.

Comment: @seccpur the point is that I don't want to use `vcpkg`, How can I find the correct order? The purpose of static library is not removing to be dependent on multiple files? I guess that `cpprestsdk_2_10.lib` contains all the dependent libs ! Am I right?

Comment: Unless it is not a big library, just put the independent libraries like boost and then higher up. For bigger open source projects ( like PCL ), just follow the installation order while vcpkg downloads and installs the package for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you don't need all those libraries, mostly you just need cpprest_2_10.lib

I did the following with success:
vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows-static-md cpprestsdk
I then linked these files:
zlib.lib
cpprest_2_10.lib

I also learned, from this issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/996) that you must also link to:
crypt32.lib
bcrypt.lib
winhttp.lib

And use this preprocessor definition:
_NO_ASYNCRTIMP=1

Comment: Here is the x64-windows-static-md triplet I made:
`set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)`
`set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)`
`set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)`
`set(VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET v141)`